# Laplace transform of products (one involves Heaviside, the other Dirac)

Tags: integration, limits, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, complex-integration

I am trying to compute the Laplace transform of a PDE, solve it in the complex Laplace space, and then compute the inverse transform. However, my PDE involves products of functions. If we consider $f$ the function to solve and $y$ the variable in the physical space ($y\ge0$), products are :

$$ f(y) H(y-y_0) $$
 and 
$$\delta_{y,y_0} \partial_y f (y) $$

Where $H$ is the Heaviside function and $\delta$ the Dirac impulsion. So far, it looks like the Laplace transform of both products would be :

$$\frac{1}{2 i \pi} \lim_{T\rightarrow+\infty} \int_{a-iT}^{a+iT} \mathscr{L} \left( f \right) \left( \sigma \right) \frac{e^{- y_0 (p-\sigma)}}{p-\sigma} d\sigma $$ and $$ \frac{1}{2 i \pi} \lim_{T\rightarrow+\infty} \int_{b-iT}^{b+iT} \left( \sigma \mathscr{L} \left( f \right) \left( \sigma \right) -f(0) \right) e^{- y_0 (p-\sigma)} d\sigma$$

First, it seems that if the function $f$ and its derivatives are vanishing quickly enough at infinity (and f has no singularity), then the choice of $a$ and $b$ is arbitrary. Please correct me if this is erroneous.

However, I can hardly solve the PDE with such integrals involving limits. Any idea to simplify them would be appreciated. For the sake of completeness, the PDE in the physical space is given below.

$$
\partial_{yy} f + \alpha \delta_{y,y_0} \partial_y f + \beta H (y-y_0) f + \gamma f = 0
$$

EDIT : the term $\alpha \delta_{y,y_0} \partial_y f (y)$ might be replaced by $\alpha \partial_y f (y_0)$ and therefore would not require any Laplace transform. However, the first derivative of $f$ is not continuous at $y_0$

EDIT2 : one way around could be to use Taylor expansion when estimating $f(y) H(y-y_0)$, so that we can express $f(y)$ as a function of $f$ and all its derivatives taken at $y-y_0$. However, not all derivatives of $f$ are continuous.

Comment: I'm not sure this is helpful at all, but $\mathcal L\left\{H(y-y_0) f(y)\right\} = e^{-y_0 s} \mathcal L\left\{f(y+y_0)\right\}$

Comment: I think that you should try to solve the equation for $y<y_0$, then for $y>y_0$ and then try to match, so that the $\delta$ is satisfied via a jump in the derivative.

Comment: After further thought, I think the delta means that the derivative vanishes at $y_0$

Comment: @user619894 I suspect my problem is ill-defined. The derivatives of the function $f$ are not continuous at $y_0$. Therefore, it is not a test function (not infinitely derivable with compact support). Thus, it looks like a bad idea to apply the Dirac impulsion on $f$ and its derivatives.

Comment: how do you know that the derivatives are not continuous?

Comment: @user619894 it is correct that my post is not very clear, and some information is missing. Thus, I have accepted your answer, the Laplace transform is not mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets consider the cases $y<y_0$ and $y>y_0$

$\partial_{yy} f  + \gamma f = 0 \,\,(y<y_0)$

$\partial_{yy} f  + (\beta+\gamma) f = 0 \,\,(y>y_0)$

with solutions:

$f_< = a e^{\sqrt{-\gamma}y} +b e^{-\sqrt{-\gamma}y}$

$f_> = c e^{\sqrt{-\beta-\gamma}y} +d e^{-\sqrt{-\beta-\gamma}y}$

lets call $\rho = \sqrt{-\gamma} ;\sigma = \sqrt{-\beta-\gamma}$

if we demand continuity and $f'(y_0)=0$ at  $y=y_0$ we can "ignore" the delta function (and its prefactor $\alpha$). This implies 3 equations for $a,b,c,d$:

$\begin{pmatrix}
e^{\rho y_0}&e^{-\rho y_0}&-e^{\sigma y_0}&-e^{-\sigma y_0}&\\
\rho e^{\rho y_0}&-\rho e^{-\rho y_0}&0&0&\\
0&0&\sigma e^{\sigma y_0}&-\sigma e^{-\sigma y_0}&\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
d\\
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

Adding a normalization $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$ we have 4 equations for 4 unknowns.

Note that $f''$ need not be continuous at $y=y_0$